# Iteration method - Matlab

Tags: matlab, iteration

Please help me with this.

I have pseudo code like this:

[image: -]

The iteration method with 3 cycles they mentioned in this pseudo code, can I use fixed point iteration like below code:

```
for n = 1:500
 Ex(n) = Ex(1);
 maxIter = 3;
 %--------Computation using Fixed point Iteration------%
 Ex(nz) = Ex(n);
 for i =  1 : maxIter
    Phi_Kx(nz) = Ex(nz).^2;
    P_LDx(nz) = (4/(2+(omega^2*dt^2)))*P_LDx(nz) - P_LDx(nz) + (2*omega^2*dt^2/(2+(omega^2*dt^2)))*Ex(nz);
    Xi_Rx(nz) = ((4-2*dt^2)/(dt*BW+2))*Xi_Rx(nz) +((dt*BW-2)/(dt*BW+2))*Xi_Rx(nz) +((2*dt^2*BW)/(dt*BW+2))* Ex(nz);
    N(nz) =((2*tau_c-dt)/(2*tau_c+dt))* N(nz) +((tau_c*dt)/(2*tau_c-dt))*(10/(4*hbar*omega))*Ex(nz).^4;
    A2 = epsilon_2.*S_Kx(nz) + Xi_Rx(nz) - (3*N(nz)-N(nz-1))+(c*n0*dt/4)*(alpha_loss+alpha_fca) + (n0^2*c^2.*epsilon*beta_tpa/4).*S_Kx(nz);
    D_NLx = Dx - P_LDx;
    Ex = (A1./A2).*Ex(nz)- (D_NLx(nz)-D_NLx(nz-1))./(epsilon.*A2);
 end
end
```

In this loop, Phi_Kx, P_LDx, Xi_Rx, N are functions of E(n) which also are calculated before

Do I need to include them inside the loop like above ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: The way the pseudo-code is written, `Phi_Kx`, `P_LDx`, `Xi_Rx` and `N` should be calculated before the loop, using the values of the previous iteration `E(n)`. However, both approaches are valid, you can include its calculation within the loop, updating them at every iteration. Notice that the latter should give better results (or faster convergence), with the expense of slower iterations.

Comment: Yes. I have code to calculate them before the for loop. So, the way I implemented the code is correct, right ? Or, should it be some changes ? Because when calculate `A_2`, the `Phi_Kx` requires value of E at n+1, so need both code for `Phi_Kx`, `P_LDx`, `Xi_Rx` and `N` outside and inside the loop, right ? Or only `Phi_Kx`, `A_2` and `E` inside the loop ?

Comment: Both strategies are fine. Your code is correct. What is your question? Is your code running fine or does it have some problems? Do you have any response to compare with the outputs of your code?

Comment: I think the problem related to central difference scheme. I have equation in the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ojoeq_IcpeY4yleqy9zLEsuhxSCkM3d2/view?usp=sharing. `P_LDx(n+1) = A*P_LDx(n) - B*P_LDx(n-1) + C*Ex(n);`. Suppose all parameters `A`, `B`, `C` are known. Do you think the above code is right ?